# Catch block doesn't want to catch thrown exception

Tags: c++, qt, exception

I have a code:

```
void Engine::count(const std::set<boost::filesystem3::path>& files)
{
    for (auto e : files)
    {
        try
        {
            count_(e);
        }
        catch (const Bad_formatting& ) // Here I'm trying to catch this exception
        {//but debugger never stops on this line even though breakpoint is set
            throw;                     // and re-throw it
        }
    }
}
```

Then there is this `count_` function:

```
void Engine::count_(const boost::filesystem3::path& file)
{
    // and somewhere along this lines I'm throwing Bad_Formatting: 

    if (something)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        throw Bad_formatting(file,"No end of multicomment found.");
    }
}
```

But after throwing this exception, I'm getting dialog telling me that my application requested runtime to terminate in an unusual way...
The exception is never cought. Why? Does the fact that both of those fncs are static has anything to do with it? Or the fact that I'm using Qt?
EDIT:
This is the code which calls count:

```
try
    {

            Engine::count(files);



    }
    catch (const Bad_formatting& e)
    {

        QMessageBox::warning(nullptr,"Bad Formatting",msg);
    }  
//// 



struct Bad_formatting : public std::runtime_error
{
private:
    boost::filesystem3::path file_name_;

public:
    Bad_formatting(boost::filesystem3::path file_name,
                   const char* msg):std::runtime_error(msg),
                                    file_name_(file_name)
    {

    }

    const boost::filesystem3::path& file_name()const
    {
        return file_name_;
    }
    ~Bad_formatting()throw()
    {/*eb*/}
};
```

Comment: You rethrow the exception out of `Engine::count()`: is there an exception handler in the caller of `Engine::count()`?

Comment: @hmjd yes, I do try to catch it, but it just doesn't do the trick

Comment: Could you post the calling code of `Engine::count()` and the `Bad_formatting` class? Might be a problem with the copying of `Bad_formatting`.

Comment: @smallB: Show the code that is catching the rethrown exception.

Comment: What is `msg` and how and where is it populated?

Comment: @hmjd msg in this case is a const char* = "Bad formatting found";

Comment: Could you show the `if (something)` branch of the code, incase a different type of exception is being thrown from there? Consider addiing `std::runtime_error` to outermost catch block to check this (guess).

Comment: @hmjd no exception is thrown in other parts of this code

Comment: (Just to be sure) You are not throwing exceptions but is there other code invoked that may throw (`std::vector::at()` for example)?

Comment: What are the platform, OS, and compiler? Do you try to throw among DLL boundaries? Does catch (...) {} catch it? Also try do de-inline the ctor and dtor of the exception. I think I saw an issue like this in an occasion where all methods of the exception were inline.

Comment: The issue with library boundaries and inline methods I was referring to is described here: http://marcmutz.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/fun-with-exceptions/

Answer (score 2):

From the code you show you

1. throw an exception;
2. catch it;
3. rethrow it;
4. **never catch it again.**

Item 4 seems to be the important part.

Comment: I do try to catch it again in a fnc which calls count

Comment: @smallB: So then your question is totally missing the point. Your code clearly *does* catch the exception, and your actual worry is what happens *elsewhere, in different code* from the code you're showing us. Why???

Comment: @smallB: Hm. OK. Can you please make a *minimal*, self-contained example that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @smallB: Ideally, "self-contained" means it contains `main()` and I can copy/paste it to my machine and compile and experience the same problem as you do... Maybe that's impossible for you to post, but it would make it *much* easier for anyone to help.

Comment: @KerrekSB project has few thousand lines, impossible.

Answer (score 0):

What compiler/toolchain/debugger are you using? If you are using GCC you can use the `catch throw` and `catch catch` commands to add breakpoints on exception throwing/catching.

As of the possible reasons that it is not being caught, if the only code in the catch block is a throw, the compiler might have optimized the whole block away. Consider adding *any* instruction to the block (note *any* might require some instruction with actual side effects, or the compiler might also optimize that away)

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.6.2. I've realized that this has something to do with the way this compiler was compiled. As soon as I plug default Qt's compiler everything works. Would you happen to know how to solve it?

Comment: @smallB: GCC can be very unhappy when mixing different versions of g++ compiled code. I have seen programs segfault because they were built with newer GCC but then dynamically linked to an older version of libstdc++.